# Firebase Database query not displaying on screen

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a class in which I show the list of friends which the user has. However, when I try to run this, the RecylerView does not show the current user the friends that they have.

**Friends Fragment**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.AlertDialogLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {


    private RecyclerView mFriendsList;
    private DatabaseReference mFriendsDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String mCurrent_user_id;
    private View mMainView;


    public FriendsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mFriendsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);
        mUsersDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mFriendsList= (RecyclerView)mMainView.findViewById(R.id.friends_list);
        mFriendsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mFriendsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mFriendsDatabase.keepSynced(true);


        return mMainView;
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        startListening();

    }
        public void startListening() {

            Query queryFriends = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference()
                    .child("Friends")
                    .child(mCurrent_user_id)
                    .limitToLast(50);

           FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Friends> options =
                    new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Friends>()
                            .setQuery(queryFriends, Friends.class)
                            .build();

           FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder> friendsRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>(options) {

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public FriendsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.friends_single_layout, parent, false);

                    return new FriendsViewHolder(view);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FriendsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Friends model) {

                    holder.setDate(model.getDate());

                    final String list_user_id= getRef(position).getKey();

                    mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("online") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("name") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("thumb_image") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("status")) {
                                final String username = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
                                String userStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                                holder.setName(username);
                                holder.setUserImage(userThumb);
                                holder.setUserStatus(userStatus);
                                boolean userOnline = (boolean) dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue();
                                holder.setUserOnline(userOnline);
                                mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);
                                mFriendsDatabase.keepSynced(true);

                                holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Open profile", "Send Message"};
                                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                                        builder.setTitle("Select Options");
                                        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                if (which == 0) {
                                                    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                                    profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                                    startActivity(profileIntent);
                                                }
                                                if (which == 1) {
                                                    Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                                    chatIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                                    chatIntent.putExtra("user_name", username);
                                                    mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);
                                                    mFriendsDatabase.keepSynced(true);
                                                    startActivity(chatIntent);

                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                        builder.show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }

            };




            mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsRecyclerViewAdapter);
            friendsRecyclerViewAdapter.startListening();
        }

            public static class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            View mView;
                public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    mView = itemView;
                }
                public void setDate(String date){
                    TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
                    userStatusView.setText(date);
                }

                public void setName(String name){
                    TextView userNameView= (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
                    userNameView.setText(name);
                }
                public void setUserImage(String thumb_image){
                    CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
                    Picasso.get().load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.accountpicture).into(userImageView);
                }
                public void setUserStatus(String status){
                    TextView userStatView= (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
                    userStatView.setText(status);
                }
                public void setUserOnline(boolean online_status){
                    ImageView userOnlineView= (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_online_icon);
                    ImageView userOffilneView= (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_offline_icon);
                    if(online_status){
                        userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        userOffilneView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                    else{
                        userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        userOffilneView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }



        }

    }
```

I debugged this as well and in the database it shows that the users are friends but the app just doesn't show the list of friends. I tried removing the .child(mCurrent_user_id) and it displayed the friends but it did that for friends of every user, not just the current user. I'm unsure why this happens...

**Database**

[image: DB]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you check the rules?

Comment: what do you mean by rules?

Comment: this one, https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/ have you managed it ?

Comment: Yes of course, I can read and write from my database without any problems. I just don't understand why I can't view the friends for the current user...

Comment: Have you debugged the code `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);` and checked what values are stored in `mFirebaseDatabase`? According to your database, there should only be one friend. Did you verify that?

Comment: Yes, I have. I've debugged many times and it correctly shows the UID of the user's friend but does not display.

Comment: @DavidVelasquez Do you know what I should do?

Comment: @moocow Provided an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took a week or so but I finally figured out what was wrong with my `RecyclerView`. It was not a problem with the code, but the XML layout. I have tabs in my application and in the main activity you swipe left/right to see Friends, Chats, or Requests. I realized that my tab was set to `match_parent`. So instead I changed the size and WA-LA I could see the list of friends!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies in only using `addValueEventListener`. That listener will only update your RecyclerView if data changes. So your friends are not showing because it's just waiting for a data change, so no data is being retrieved. You need to use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to get the current friend list from the DB when you first set the adapter to the RecyclerView. Create the RecyclerView adapter with that list. And then in `onBindViewHolder()`, keep your `addValueEventListener` which should update your list items accordingly when your friend data changes (although I think this is overkill; no need to add listeners to your friend items to check if data changes unless that's a key feature in your app. You could just refresh the list whenever the user goes back to that activity/fragment).

Edit:
You could set the listener in either `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`, depending on wherever you initialize the needed variables. Once you have received the response and you have your friend list, then you set it to your recyclerview adapter. Once your adapter is setup, then set it to your recyclerview. It should display your friend list.

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you mean. Where should I add the addListenerForSingleValueEvent?

Comment: @moocow Updated my answer

Comment: Ah, sorry but I still don't understand. I can't use the method addListenerForSingleValueEvent on my RecyclerView

Comment: No you set `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` on your `mFriendsDatabase` object since that object holds a reference to your ID in Firebase. Doing that will retrieve your list of friends. THEN you use that list to create your recycler view.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. How do I reference the other user though?

Comment: @moocow Have to do something at work now, so I'll update you later tonight. Good luck man!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177230/discussion-between-moo-cow-and-david-velasquez).